# egen and group when data has missing values

Tags: stata

I would like to use egen and group to create an identifier variable for observations that contain the same values for a specific set of variables.  However, some of the variables contain missing data, resulting in the corresponding identifier having a missing value.  Is there a way to get around this (other than filling in some random value for the moment)?

For example, I have variables v1 and v2.  I want observations to have a unique id if they have the same values for v1 and v2.  I want to do something like:

```
egen id = group(v1 v2)
```

Comment: Please say at least something about the variables or give us the sample data.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `missing` option of `group()` in `egen`.

By the way, the `label` option is also usually a good idea.